# Bootstrap text formatting using input-group and input-group-addon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this small problem with the code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4eocgg4/). I am using Bootstrap 3.2.0: [bootstrap.min.js](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js) and [bootstrap.min.css](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css). The code in the jsfiddle is as follows:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <label>
        <input>
      </label>
    </span>
    <label type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." >Line 2 hello world this line needs to be very long and this should do it!</label>
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
</div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <label>
        <input>
      </label>
    </span>
    <label type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." >Line 2 hello world this line needs to be very long and this should do it!</label>
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
</div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <label>
        <input>
      </label>
    </span>
    <label type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." >Line 2 hello world this line needs to be very long and this should do it!</label>
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
</div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
```

This HTML WORKS with bootstrap 3.0.0, but NOT with 3.2.0. SO, here is the SAME HTML in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3owsbnt/) but with bootstrap 3.0.0. This is how I would like it to look (but I need to use 3.2.0 because I have built my entire project in that so far...)

Any ideas on what the difference is between 3.0.0 and 3.2.0 that is causing this?

Comment: "`<label type="text`" WTF!?

Comment: haha sorry I don't really know what you're getting at. I removed that in the jsfiddle and it changed nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/a4eocgg4/1/

and this in your css:

```
 .form-control{height: auto !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the css inline with the HTML and it worked like a charm!